# make spring test method NOT transactional

Tags: java, spring, testing, transactions

I have this class

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
public class CandidateServiceTest extends AbstractServiceTest {
        @Test
    public void add() {
        }
}


@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml" })
public class AbstractServiceTest  extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{
 ...
}
```

There are exist way that method `add()` was not transactional ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@NotTransactional` annotation.

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
public class CandidateServiceTest extends AbstractServiceTest {

    @Test
    @NotTransactional
    public void add() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Since `@NotTransactional` is deprecated, Spring documentation suggests that you split the transactional and non-transactional tests in different classes.

Comment: thanks, but in javaDoc write that it is deprecated annotation and I must use BeforeTransaction or AfterTransaction. But I don't understand  how I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate a test method with `org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback` annotation with true or false arg

Comment: If I invoke two transactional methods inside method add I want use TWO transactionals

Comment: Видимо по русски будет понятнее. Я так понял, эта аннотация управляет откатывать транзакцию после выполнения метода или нет. А мой вопрос о том как сделать так, чтобы на тест не открывалась новая транзакция.